# Get items recursively inside SoapObject

Tags: java, android, android-ksoap2

I have all classes generated from WSDL2KSoap and I receive response from envelope.bodyIn as normal. My envelope.bodyIn.toString() looks like this.

```
getCatResponse{
    getCatResult=anyType{
        returnCode=200;
        category=anyType{
            Category=anyType{
                code=101;
                name=Games;
            };
            Category=anyType{
                code=102;
                name=Apps;
            };
        };
    };
}
```

How do I get each one out of this SoapObject. Right now, I can only use soapResult.getProperty(name). Can I cast it to my getCatResponse.java that I have?

Answer (score 0):

```
SoapObject soapResult = (SoapObject) result;
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
soapResult.getPropertyInfo(0, pi);

SoapObject soapResult2 = (SoapObject) pi.getValue();
PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
soapResult2.getPropertyInfo(2, pi2);

SoapObject soapResult3 = (SoapObject) pi2.getValue();
PropertyInfo pi3 = new PropertyInfo();
soapResult3.getPropertyInfo(0, pi3);
Log.i(LOG, pi3.toString());
```

Oh, Use getPropertyInfo. you will get this from the code above

```
Category=anyType{
    code=101;
    name=Games;
};
```